# How to use Row_Number to group a resultset

Tags: sql-server, group-by, row-number

i'm stuck with a query and i don't want to use a while loop or another nasty method to do this.

Here's the situation:

I've got a query that gets some data, and i need to calculate a column based on 2 other columns.

My results are as follow:
Type | Customer | Cycle | Amount | Expiration | Row_Number (Partition By Customer, Cycle)

So, my row_number column needs to "group" customers and cycles, here's a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/506c0/3) to better understand it

Here's an example:
[image: My actual results]

As you can see, iteration column is correctly applied as far as i know what row_number does.
But i need to do this:
[image: How i need my data]

Is there a way to do this with Row_Number ?

or should i need store the data in a temp table, loop through it and update this ITERATION column?

Maybe a CTE?
Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/506c0/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [DENSE_RANK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) function instead of ROW_NUMBER.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    Customer NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Cycle] SMALLINT NOT NULL
);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('C1', 2010);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('C1', 2010);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('C1', 2011);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('C1', 2012);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('C1', 2012);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('C1', 2012);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('C2', 2010);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('C2', 2010);

SELECT  t.Customer, t.[Cycle], 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Customer ORDER BY t.[Cycle]) AS Rnk
FROM    @MyTable t
ORDER BY Customer, [Cycle];
```

Results:

```
Customer Cycle  Rnk
-------- ------ ---
C1       2010   1
C1       2010   1
C1       2011   2
C1       2012   3
C1       2012   3
C1       2012   3
C2       2010   1
C2       2010   1
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26497)</kbd>

Comment: Could you show me how to do it on the fiddle i posted? i tried many combinations but it always returns 1 on each row.  Select *, Dense_Rank() Over(Partition By Customer, Cycle Order By Cycle)
From Test

Comment: Oh i got it, i was trying to partition it by Customer and cycle, the trick is to partition it only by customer... Why is that? I mean, my group is based on those 2 columns, shouldn't the partition be by it too?

Comment: @SamCcp: `PARTITION BY` sub-clause is used to restart the "numbering". So `PARTITION BY Customer, Cycle` will restarting the "numbering" for every (customer, cycle) pair.

Comment: Yeah, i was confused with that, i thought it worked the opposite. Thanks a lot @Bogdan Sahlean, you've earned a fan.

Answer (score 4):

just run this as new query, replace what you need in your query...

```
WITH T(StyleID, ID)
     AS (SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
         SELECT 1,2)
SELECT *,
      RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY StyleID ORDER BY ID)       AS 'RANK',
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StyleID ORDER BY ID) AS 'ROW_NUMBER',
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY StyleID ORDER BY ID) AS 'DENSE_RANK'
FROM   T
```

regards,
Valentin

Comment: Thanks mate, your answer is spot on, but Mr. Bogdan beat you to it by mere seconds. Thanks a lot for your help.